# FCM custom handling of onMessageReceived function in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing FCM for unity and I need to send some stats when the Push Notifications are received by the android client.

For that, if app is in foreground I am able to handle the scenario. But if the app is killed/background, I am not able to handle the scenario.

Can anyone help in achieving this scenario.

For this I came across https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/client#custom_message_handling_on_android

I tried to Override ListenerService Methods and for this approach I tried to create a jar but whenever I am not able to import the "com.google.firebase.messaging.cpp.ListenerService".

Can you please suggest how can I achieve this functionailty

Answer (score 1):

First, the jar you're missing is part of the Firebase C++ SDK. In a normal C++ and Android project, you'd have something like:

```
apply from: "$gradle.firebase_cpp_sdk_dir/Android/firebase_dependencies.gradle"
firebaseCpp.dependencies {
  messaging
}
```

If you want to go the "creating a jar" route, you'll need to reference those dependencies *but* also not collide with the External Dependency Manager for Unity (EDM4U). I'd recommend [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef) on what's going on there, but it's probably more convenient to have [free floating Java or Kotlin files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidJavaSourcePlugins.html) and letting EDM4U do its thing.

With that said, I believe that you *should not* need to configure that method in Unity. You should see this [table](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#note_about_message_delivery_on_android) to see what you can and can't handle in the foreground and background. If you're sending a data message (rather than a notification message) and [MessageReceived](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#initialize) is not triggered, then you may have to do [some native Android activity work](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#configuring_an_android_entry_point_activity) (from the Unity documentation rather than the C++ linked in the OP).

Remember that [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#configuring_an_android_entry_point_activity) *only* applies if you have a custom Activity on Android, either you set one up or another plugin did. You'll need to [override onNewIntent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client#configuring_a_custom_entry_point_activity) to send the data to a [MessageForwardingService](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blob/master/messaging/src/android/java/com/google/firebase/messaging/MessageForwardingService.java). There's also some explicit cleanup to be done in `onCreate`, I've pasted the entire sample below:

```
/**
 * Workaround for when a message is sent containing both a Data and Notification payload.
 *
 * When the app is in the background, if a message with both a data and notification payload is
 * received the data payload is stored on the Intent passed to onNewIntent. By default, that
 * intent does not get set as the Intent that started the app, so when the app comes back online
 * it doesn't see a new FCM message to respond to. As a workaround, we override onNewIntent so
 * that it sends the intent to the MessageForwardingService which forwards the message to the
 * FirebaseMessagingService which in turn sends the message to the application.
 */
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  Intent message = new Intent(this, MessageForwardingService.class);
  message.setAction(MessageForwardingService.ACTION_REMOTE_INTENT);
  message.putExtras(intent);
  message.setData(intent.getData());
  startService(message);
}

/**
 * Dispose of the mUnityPlayer when restarting the app.
 *
 * This ensures that when the app starts up again it does not start with stale data.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (mUnityPlayer != null) {
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
    mUnityPlayer = null;
  }
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

If neither of those work with forwarding the message, file a bug [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) or [on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues). If you're still running into missing dependency issues, you may need to use a [custom gradle template](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html) in Unity and maybe add your new code as a module. Then you can properly use [implementation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) and work with EDM4U.

I know that this is a lot to unpack, so let me know if you still have any specific questions!

--Patrick

Comment: I tried this... The above code impacts when the notification is received in the notification tray and then user clicks on the notification.
I wanted to make changes to handle the notification before it is received in the notification tray